# Get country code from short NSLocal identifier

Tags: objective-c, nslocale

```
   NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"]; 
   NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
   NSLog(@"countryCode %@",countryCode);
```

trying to get ISOCountryCode from **SHORT** localIdentifier

- (I'm using the whole world identifiers)
- trying to return there CountryCode (in English)

  > e.g: "en_UK" return value, but only "en" returns nil.
- localeWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_UK" == OK
- localeWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en" == not ok

Comment: Which english locale do you want to use? Australia, Canada, Ireland, India, New Zealand, Singapore, US or South Africa?

Comment: I'm using the whole world identifiers
trying to return there CountryCode (in English)

Comment: Are you trying to use the current locale? Use `[NSLocale currentLocale]`.

Answer (score 3):

If your [Locale ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH15-SW9) is just a language code it represents:

> An unspecified region where the language is used.

So there is no country code for `en`, many regions use English. Specify a Locale ID which includes a region designator, such as `en_GB`, if you need an `NSLocale` which represents a language and a region.

If you wish to discover all the regions your system knows which use a particular language then look at `NSLocale`'s `availableLocaleIdentifiers` class method.

HTH